# Get Browser logs and make TestNG test fail if there are any SEVERE logs from browser console

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, ui-automation, console.log

I'm Designing an automation framework using Selenium+TestNG+Java.
I want to check browser logs, if there are any SEVERE logs while executing any tests, it should mark the test as FAIL.

I'm able to identify the way to fetch the browser logs and able to add it in my internal logger.

```
public void analyzeBrowserLogs() {
        String type = "browser";
        List<LogEntry> entries = driver.manage().logs().get(type).getAll();
        System.out.println(entries.size() + " " + type + " log entries found");
        for (LogEntry entry : entries) {
            //if(entry.getMessage().contains("SEVERE"))
                System.out.println(new Date(entry.getTimestamp()) + " " + entry.getLevel() + " " + entry.getMessage());
        }
    }
```

I got stuck how could I check logs continually while executing the TestCases and If any SEVERE error occurs in logs, I need to mark the corresponding test status as FAIL.

It would be great addition to my framework if I'm able to design this logger feature.

Answer (score 0):

Continuously polling the logs while the browser is basically running your test would not only be an overkill, but it may also cause flaky results.

So its not advisable to have your poll logs from browser, while test is running, happen in parallel.

What you should be doing is:

1. Leverage `EventFiringWebDriver` (see javadocs [here](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/events/EventFiringWebDriver.html)) as your WebDriver implementation instead of `RemoteWebDriver` when your framework instantiates webdriver.
2. Plug in a custom implementation of `WebDriverEventListener` (see javadocs [here](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/events/WebDriverEventListener.html)) wherein you would identify events that cause javascript to get executed (usually its when a new page loads ) and for those events, within its `afterXXX` method, you make a call to your `analyzeBrowserLogs()` and if there's a SEVERE error, you throw an exception, which causes TestNG to automatically fail your test